# Grails Many to one Relationship deletion

Tags: grails, foreign-keys

```
class First {
    String text
    Second second

    static constraints = {
    }
}

class Second {
    String name

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

When I delete Second class object, I got an error like this:

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails.
```

I want to delete only the instance of Second inside First.

Comment: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#cascades

Comment: I want First Object have to live,But the field of second have to bacome null or empty when second object get deleted

Answer (score 0):

You have to `remove` the association of `Second` from `First` (aka FK constraint) and then will be able to delete `Second`.

```
first.second = null
second.delete()
```

Refer [removeFrom](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/removeFrom.html) for more details when one-many & many-many relations are used.

Comment: first.second=null second.delete(flush:true).We cant use removeFrom. Because second inside First class is a single object.Not collections.